# Top level delegate reference cannot be resolved

Tags: c#

I have a test like this:

```cs
delegate int Mapper(string str);

public class MappingTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MapFromStringToInt()
    {
        Mapper stringToIntMapper = (string text) => { return int.Parse(text); };
        var x = stringToIntMapper("1");
        Assert.Equal(1, x);
    }
}
```

I can move the declaration of `stringToIntMapper` outside the test `class` like this:

```cs
delegate int Mapper(string str);
Mapper stringToIntMapper = (string text) => { return int.Parse(text); };

public class MappingTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MapFromStringToInt()
    {
        var x = stringToIntMapper("1");
        Assert.Equal(1, x);
    }
}
```

How can I access `stringToIntMapper` in my test (or any other class/method)? Now the compiler says it cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare variables outside of a class. If you want your variable to be globally accessable, you can put it into a static class:

```
public static class DelegateCollection
{
    public static readonly Mapper stringToIntMapper = (string text) => { return int.Parse(text); };
}
```

You can access it via

```
DelegateCollection.stringToIntMapper
```

But you should make sure that your static class is stateless, e.g. by making everything inside this class readonly. Otherwise, your code becomes hard to test and you might get bugs which are hard to find.

Comment: Explicit statelessness was the reasonn why I wanted to use a delegate without any context surrounding it.

Answer (score -1):

Just make it a method:

```
static int StringToIntMapper(string text) {
    return int.Parse(text);
}
```